# Linux RAID0 - relocating member disk

Tags: raid, software-raid, raid0

I've got an issue I would rather handle with the array online - I am using RAID0 for temporary video storage - data that is low-cost to restore, but that is used frequently.

The software array looks like this:

```
md1 : active raid0 sdb1[2] sdc1[3] sdd1[0] sde1[1]
      1953487616 blocks 64k chunks
```

I have another partition (sda1) in this system, that I want to use to replace sdc1 (The drives are of varying age, and sdc1 is definitely the slowest one, limiting the entire array's sequential read performance to only 300MB/s).

Is there a way to migrate the data from sdc1 to sda1 while the array is still online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this online, because RAID-0 is completely incapable of handling failures, and the md system depends on failures to trigger rebuilds onto spare components.  There is no way to say "can you please use *this* device instead of *that* device" without saying "*that* device has failed" -- which, of course, is going to give your RAID-0 array a conniption.

For this reason, I'd recommend using LVM and striping instead of md for RAID-0 arrays.  It has a much better toolset for managing component devices like this.  I'd still use md for any other RAID level, though.

Comment: Thanks, it's very informative - I would rather stick with RAID0, and just offline the array overnight, dd and reassemble - mostly because LVM striping appears a bit challenging to finetune performance (stripe location and drive rotation synchronization)

Answer (score 0):

Typically doing anything like that with RAID 0 requires rebuilding the array from scratch.

Comment: Well, not quite - it doesn't reshape the array, merely moves the data around - so there shouldn't be any need for rebuilding the array. 

In fact, to do so offline, I would merely copy (dd) sdc1 to sda1 and manually override the array assembly, specifying the new drive order.

Comment: +1 to qdot. This seems entirely workable based off my previous experience with mdraid.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't replace raid0 disk while array is online. But you can do this after stopping raid (i just temporarily commented out contents of my */etc/mdadm.conf* and rebooted). While raid is offline you can just copy entire disk from faulty one to the new disk using "dd" cmdline utility. After cloning uncommment contents of */etc/mdadm.conf* back, then **shutdown**, DISCONNECT FAULTY DISK(!) and boot again.

Answer (score 0):

It [*might*](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-938092-start-0.html) be possible to upgrade your RAID 0 to RAID 5, then yank out sdc1, leaving you with a degraded RAID 5.